# Magento 1.7 CategoryController Override - Add Tail to URL

Tags: magento, controller, url-rewriting, overriding

It was easy enough to override the category controller to add an action but I am stuck on figuring out how to keep the same url format.

I am adding a sitemap to each category. My goal is to add a "tail" to my category url so that it looks like this:

```
http://www.lightsnholsters.com/furniture/sitemap/
```

Where the category is furniture. Currently, I can access my sitemap page when the url is structured like this:

```
http://www.lightsnholsters.com/catalog/category/sitemap/id/23/
```

But I want the SEO friendly url structure that magento uses for its categories.

I overrode Mage_Catalog_CategoryController with this little bit in config.xml

```
</frontend> 
  <routers>
    <catalog>
      <args>
        <modules>
          <Lightsnholsters_CategorySitemap before="Mage_Catalog">Lightsnholsters_CategorySitemap</Lightsnholsters_CategorySitemap>
        </modules>
      </args>
    </catalog>
  </routers>    
</frontend>
```

Thank you for getting me pointed in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get rid of excessive lines of the code is as follows:

- Create your own controller or rewrite Mage_Catalog as you already did
- Add sitemapAction() method
- Go to Catalog > URL Rewrite Management > Add URL Rewrite
- Chose "Custom" URL Rewrite
- Fill the form:
  ID Path: Any
  Request Path: furniture/sitemap/
  Target Path: catalog/category/sitemap/id/23/
  Redirect: No

This solution will work fine in case a store doesn't have too many categories. Otherwise, the whole process of adding new URL rewrites will become a daunting task.